# sentence-final "really"

Tags: word-order

In the following sentence, why is "really" placed at the end of the sentence?
Is it an afterthought?

> I suppose delivery in two days is pretty fast, **really**.

Comment: If someone said something like this in your language, would it sound like an afterthought?

Comment: Probably it's used to show the speaker just realizes the listener might have doubts about what s/he has just said.

Comment: Same in English, really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example "really" is used to refer to the reality of a situation in contrast to the appearance of the situation. The delivery appeared to be somewhat slow, but in reality it was pretty fast. Often such statements are made after thinking through the process steps involved and realising that the appearance (of slowness) is caused by not having thought deeply enough.

Comment: Are you suggesting it is an afterthought?

Comment: @Apollyon, no, the word “really” is not an afterthought. The realisation that two days is quick rather than slow may come after some extra thought (or more information). It may also be come after somebody else has remarked on the slowness.